# Sharepoint Search Created By field in Search results not consistent

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I am using a blog aggregator (**CoreResultsWebPart**) returning all blog posts from my mysites.
I am trying to retrieve the login name of the user who created the blog post in my xsl.

However I am getting inconsistent results. eg:

User login: **mydomain\maggie.smith**

Returned data for author : **mydomain\maggie.smith** (CORRECT!)

Another user login : **mydomain\bob.hope**

Returned data for author : **Bob Hope**

Now I am assuming that its because the user profile database fetched the display name of Bob hope because that information exists, however, instead of "Bob Hope", I want to get his login name! If I use sharepoint manager to inspect the blog post for 'Bob Hope', all the Created By and Author fields show 'Bob Hope' and not mydomain\bob.hope.

How do I get it? The reason being is to get the users profile picture to attach to my xsl blog aggregation.

I have added other metadata columns to return and recrawled the content source but I cant get the login name of the original author. Help anyone, please!

Answer (score 1):

SPUserField has "Show field" setting. Try to change this to show Login instead of DisplayName for your "CreatedBy" field and see if it would help.

Comment: How would I go about setting this in the search?